# Output Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL connection string with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

I am currently trying to deploy an [Azure Cosmos DB PostgreSQL cluster with Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_postgresql_cluster).

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_postgresql_cluster" "example" {
  name                            = "example-cluster"
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  location                        = var.resource_group_location
  administrator_login_password    = ""
  coordinator_storage_quota_in_mb = 131072
  coordinator_vcore_count         = 2
  node_count                      = 0
}
```

---

It works but I wanted to know if there is a way to output the **connection string** of the databases at the end of the deployment so I can use an SQL init script to create all the schemas and tables needed ?

I'am pretty new to Terraform and I have read the *"Attributes Reference"* of the documentations but don't if I am right.

I also already read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937964/how-to-output-the-cosmos-db-connection-string-using-terraform) but it does not word since the "connection_strings" field does not exists in my case.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It seems connection strings are provided by a different resource, the one you are referencing in your question, called `azurerm_cosmosdb_account`. Do you have that resource somewhere in your code? Can you see the list of [connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/postgresql/quickstart-connect-psql) in the UI?

Comment: No the only resources in my code are `azurerm_cosmosdb_postgresql_cluster`and  `azurerm_cosmosdb_postgresql_firewall_rule`. In the UI there is no mention connect strings or related field

Comment: @DonovanHOANG azurerm_cosmosdb_account - support for the primary_sql_connection_string, secondary_sql_connection_string, primary_readonly_sql_connection_string, and secondary_readonly_sql_connection_string attributes [#17810](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/17810)

Answer (score 0):

Cluster created for cosmos db for postgres sql   doesn’t have direct properties to retrieve connection string.

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_postgresql_cluster" "example" {
  name                            = "examplekcluster"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  administrator_login_password    = "kavyadmin@123"
  coordinator_storage_quota_in_mb = 131072
  coordinator_vcore_count         = 2
  node_count                      = 0
}
```

[image]
host = "c-..postgres.cosmos.azure.com"
dbname = "citus"
user = "citus"
password = ""
sslmode = "require"

[image]

Format:

```
psql "host=c-<cluster>.<uniqueID>.postgres.cosmos.azure.com port=5432 dbname=citus user=citus password={your_password} sslmode=require
```

One  way is to use a variable to configure /construct  the connection_strings, and out put the values.

```
output "cosmosdb_connectionstrings" {
   value = "host=c-${azurerm_cosmosdb_postgresql_cluster.example.name}.${var.uniqueID}.postgres.cosmos.azure.com port=5432;dbname=citus;user=citus;password=${azurerm_cosmosdb_postgresql_cluster.example.administrator_login_password};sslmode=require"
   sensitive   = true
}
```

Know the format from portal and configure the same way for other clusters using variables and referencing resource blocks.

[image]

```
terraform apply
```

[image]

References:

1. [Retrieve connection endpoint for Azure cosmosdb for Postgresql Cluster by CLI - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488010/retrieve-connection-endpoint-for-azure-cosmosdb-for-postgresql-cluster-by-cli#:%7E:text=To%20retrieve%20the%20connection%20strings%2C%20use%20the%20AzCLI,keys%20list%20--type%20connection-strings%20--name%20%3Ccosmosdbaccount%3E%20--resource-group%20%3Cresourcegroup%3E)
2. [howto-create-azure-cosmos-db-for-postgresql-cluster-with-terraform |StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531787/howto-create-azure-cosmos-db-for-postgresql-cluster-with-terraform)

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I am not sure to understand from where you retrieve the `var.uniqueID` ?

Comment: I also don't know how you get the value to put in the var.uniqueID